# XDoclet Ant Tasks Not Respecting force="true" Attribute

Tags: ant, xdoclet

I've been running into some issues with the [ejbdoclet](http://xdoclet.sourceforge.net/xdoclet/ant/xdoclet/modules/ejb/EjbDocletTask.html) Ant task, specifically, it is giving me output such as the following:

> [ejbdoclet] XJavaDoc Ignoring class **myClass** in
>   **/path/myClass.java**. It was generated (Wed Mar 28 16:59:12 EDT 2012) after XJavaDoc's timestamp was reset (Wed Mar 28 16:58:52 EDT
>   2012)

You will note that the file is being ignored because it was generated after the timestamp on the file. The source files are currently sitting on an NFS share connected to the build cluster and for various resasons, generating the files on the local machines will not be posible. As such, I have used the `force="true"` tag as documented as follows:

```
<ejbdoclet ejbSpec="2.0" destdir="${common.generated}" force="true">
```

However, it is not being respected by XDoclet, any thoughts as to what might be going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oddly enough, this appears to be an error where the message that was provided didn't accurately reflect what was expected. The error message indicates that the file is being ignored due to the fact that it's date stamp is in the future when compared to the one that ejbdoclet is using to determine if the files should be generated. This actually bypasses the force attribute so the error is actually with regards to the system clocks not being synchronized as opposed to with ejbdoclet itself per se.

Comment: Sorry your answer doesn't make any sense to me ... how did you actually resolve the issue??

Comment: @KhaledE We made sure the system clocks were synchronized in the build cluster.

Comment: thanks for your response ... your use case is different than mine. I am wondering how XDoclet is figuring out the time to compare to ? I've deleted all the generated files!

Comment: @KhaledE It's been a couple years, but I seem to recall we were running into a similar question. Turned out it was using the system time of the server that started the build as the reference time and the other servers were running at a different time.